# Background image stretched in <a> tag

Tags: css

I have background image in **a** tag.

```
a{ background:url("../images/image.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    display: block;
    height: 76px;
    width: 87px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

It display Streched but, if I remove the `position:absolute`, it is sharp.

But I need `position:absolute`.

Help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the `background-size` property to define the size of the background:

```
background-size: 87px 76px;
```

**Source(s)**

[MDN - CSS Background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background)
[MDN - CSS Background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size)

Comment: This should work, but I did have the width/height the wrong way round :s Please try again and if not, maybe set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

Create Image of the same size. `height:76px; width:87px;`

then it will not stretch.